# Fixing data path not found error with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I've got the sqlite db working in the editor just fine. However when using it in Android, I get an error saying data path not found.

I believe I have the needed libsqlite.so files in the correct plugins/ android folder and the other DLLs that the editor looks for.

Here is my code:

```
string filepath = Application.dataPath + "/" + "Players.db"; //.db

if(!File.Exists(filepath))
{
    // if it doesn't ->
    // open StreamingAssets directory and load the db ->

    try {
        WWW loadDB = new WWW ("jar:file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "!/Assets/" + "StreamingAssets/Players.db");  // .db this is the path to your StreamingAssets in android

        while (!loadDB.isDone) {
        }  // CAREFUL here, for safety reasons you shouldn't let this while loop unattended, place a timer and error check

        // then save to Application.persistentDataPath

        File.WriteAllBytes (filepath, loadDB.bytes);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        GameObject.Find ("Advice").GetComponent<Text> ().text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Application.DataPath` to save files. In editor mode it refers to Assets folder but in android build it refers to APK package which is a compressed file and you have no access to it. So use `Application.persistentDataPath` instead.

```
string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "Players.db"; //.db
```

Comment: hi, I've tried that as well in the past, in those cases, not only does it fail in android, it also fails in the editor

Comment: what do you mean by **it fails...**. Do you get any specific error? And make sure you set write access to external (SDCard) from player settings.